# Is there a way to get Anchor to use enum defaults?

Tags: anchor, rust

It seems that Anchor isn't using default values on enums.

I create an account containing an enum with a `Default`, and don't set a value on that enum. Example `lib.rs`:

```
#![feature(derive_default_enum)]
use anchor_lang::prelude::*;

// This is your program's public key and it will update
// automatically when you build the project.
declare_id!("HENtWdUyz7yv1rkopkt4jsd1A6tgZt8QPkKuk7KtqFb7");

#[program]
mod hello_anchor {
    use super::*;
    pub fn initialize(ctx: Context<Initialize>) -> Result<()> {
        msg!("Initialized!");
        Ok(())
    }
}

#[derive(AnchorSerialize, AnchorDeserialize, Clone, Default)]
pub enum Hello {
    X,
    #[default]
    Y,
}

#[account]
pub struct HelloAccount {
    data: Hello
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Initialize<'info> {
    #[account(init, payer = signer, space = 100)]
    pub hello_account: Account<'info, HelloAccount>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub signer: Signer<'info>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}
```

Playground link: https://beta.solpg.io/630dd93888a7fca897ad7d0a

If I call the `initialize` method, and then fetch the created account it has this structure:

```
{
  "data": {
    "x": {}
  }
}
```

I'd have expected it to have the `y` value since that's the default in the enum and I didn't set it.

Similarly if I create an account containing an array of these enums. Example `lib.rs`:

```
#![feature(derive_default_enum)]
use anchor_lang::prelude::*;

// This is your program's public key and it will update
// automatically when you build the project.
declare_id!("995YWZuGkLpcC6Q8itToMhJrnaYwwLTzUViWdui8eJU2");

#[program]
mod hello_anchor {
    use super::*;
    pub fn initialize(ctx: Context<Initialize>) -> Result<()> {
        msg!("Initialized!");
        Ok(())
    }
}

#[derive(AnchorSerialize, AnchorDeserialize, Clone, Copy, Default)]
pub enum Hello {
    X,
    #[default]
    Y,
}

#[account]
pub struct HelloAccount {
    data: [Hello; 3]
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Initialize<'info> {
    #[account(init, payer = signer, space = 100)]
    pub hello_account: Account<'info, HelloAccount>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub signer: Signer<'info>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}
```

Playground link: beta.solpg.io/630dda3c88a7fca897ad7d0b

Again I call initialize and fetch the created account. It looks like this:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "x": {}
    },
    {
      "x": {}
    },
    {
      "x": {}
    }
  ]
}
```

Again the array is initialized with all `x` values when the default is `y`.

Is there a way to get Anchor to initialize using the default value?

Also note that in the second case (with the array), there's a rust compile error if `Default` is not derived for the enum, which is fixed when I derive it. There's also a rust compile error if I have the `Default` derive and don't include the `#[default]`. So I'm not sure what I'm missing here.

Edit: I've also opened a bug in the Anchor repo: https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor/issues/2159

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR -- You will still need to set the initial values you want manually in the body of your instruction that creates the account.

```
    pub fn initialize(ctx: Context<Initialize>) -> Result<()> {
        let hello_account = &mut ctx.accounts.hello_account;
        hello_account.data = [Hello::Y, Hello::Y, Hello::Y];
        msg!("Initialized!");
        Ok(())
    }
```

The reason this is happening is because account data is initialized as all zeroes (and your X variant corresponds to zero), and the Rust types you're using are an [abstraction over account data](https://borsh.io/) that the Solana runtime knows nothing about. So by itself, the `create_account` instruction therefore cannot even in principle know how to populate default account data. You'll have to manually specify that in your Anchor code.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have to implement (`impl`) default for each enum you want to use default values for.

```
#[account]
#[derive(Default)]
pub struct HelloAccount {
    data: Hello
}

#[derive(AnchorSerialize, AnchorDeserialize, Clone, Copy)]
pub enum Hello {
    X,
    Y,
}

impl Default for Hello {
  fn default() -> Self {
    Hello::Y
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Do you by any chance have an example of this being used? I've tried modifying my playground to use it and I'm still getting that `"x": {}` default. Updated playground link: https://beta.solpg.io/63164599bb7e0b5f4ca6df9b

Comment: Try deriving `Default` on the `HelloAccount` struct

Comment: Still no luck, unfortunately! https://beta.solpg.io/6317b192bb7e0b5f4ca6dfa0